# How do I show that the set of natural number N has the same size as NxN?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How do I show that the set of natural numbers $\mathbb{N}$ has the same size as $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$?
I know that for two sets to have the same size, there must be an injection from the set $\mathbb{N}$ to the set $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$ and there must be and injection from the set $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$ to the set $\mathbb{N}$.

But I have no idea on how to prove this.

Comment: and what is the relation with my question? Can't I show it only using definition of injective function?

Comment: It's literally the same question. "Countable" means "has the same size as $\mathbb{N}$", so it's exactly asking how to show that $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$ have the same size. Did you look at Asaf's answer?

Comment: Consider splitting $\mathbb{N}$ into disjoint subsets of primes $p_n$ such that $\mathbf{P}_n = \{ p_n^a | a \in \mathbb{N} \}$. Consider how these sets can map to pairs $(a,b)$.

Comment: $f(m,n) = 2^m (2n + 1) − 1$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take any $n\in\Bbb N$.

One can find $n_1$ and $n_2$ such that $ n = 2^{n_1}n_2$.

Essentially,it extracts the odd and even part of $n$.

So, $n_1$ and $n_2$ are unique.

Hence by this one can find a bijection from $\Bbb N$ to $\Bbb N \times (\Bbb N\setminus 2\Bbb N)$

$\Bbb N\setminus 2\Bbb N$ is the set of all odd integers.

Now, since $\Bbb N$ is equinumerous to $\Bbb N\setminus 2\Bbb N$.(Argue)

So, $\Bbb N$ and $\Bbb N\times\Bbb N$ are equinumerous.

Comment: is that n= (2 to the power of n1 ) times n2 ?

Comment: yes. Essentially you are extracting the even part(some power of 2) by the $n_1$

Answer (score 4):

The maps $(m,n)\mapsto 2^m\cdot 3^n$ and $n\mapsto (n,0)$ are injections. Now we may apply the Schröder–Bernstein theorem.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in many ways. Here is one:

First get all pairs of numbers with sum 0, then with sum 1, then sum 2, etc.:

So:

(0,0), (0,1), (1,0), (0,2), (1,1), (2,0), (0,3), (1,2), (2,1), (3,0), etc.

Notice that for every sum $i$, there are only finitely many ($i+1$ to be exact) pairs $(m,n)$ that have that sum, meaning that for every number $i$, you will get to all the pairs with sum $i$, and since every pair of numbers $(m,n)$ has a finite sum $i$, it is bound to appear somewhere on this list.

And now that you have a list, you have a one to one mapping:

1<->(0,0)

2<->(0,1)

3<->(1,0)

4<->(0,2)

etc.

Answer (score 1):

What you can also do is find a bijection between the two sets.

Consider the function:$$f: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$$

$$f(x)\begin{cases} 
      (\frac{m+n-1}{2}+n):if\ m+n-1 \ is \ odd\\
      ({\frac{m+n-1}{2}}+m)  : if\ m+n-1 \ is \ even \\
        \end{cases}$$
Try to make a graph, and check that is indeed a bijection.
(if you are unsure about the bijection rule, if $f$ is a bijection, then $f^{-1}$ exists, and it is also a bijection, so you have two injections you required)